# Using a while loop in another while loop to output specific data

Tags: php

I have a while loop that outputs users that have open tickets based on a mysql query. I also have another while loop that outputs all open tickets. They both work. I tried to put the second while loop in the first in such a way that i can list each user with their open tickets. I used "in_array(). The problem is that it Outputs the first user and tickets, but doesnt for the rest.

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'tickets2') or die('Error connecting to Mysql Server');

$query1 = " SELECT DISTINCT number, username, subject, o.name " .
"FROM ost_ticket t, ost_staff s, ost_ticket__cdata d, ost_user u, ost_organization o " .
"WHERE status_id = 1 AND t.staff_id=s.staff_id AND d.ticket_id=t.ticket_id AND u.id=t.user_id AND o.id=u.org_id " .
"ORDER by username" ;

$query2 = " SELECT DISTINCT username " .
"FROM ost_ticket t, ost_staff s, ost_ticket__cdata d, ost_user u, ost_organization o " .
"WHERE status_id = 1 AND t.staff_id=s.staff_id AND d.ticket_id=t.ticket_id AND u.id=t.user_id AND o.id=u.org_id " .
"ORDER by username" ;

$tickets = mysqli_query($dbc, $query1) or die ('Error');

$users = mysqli_query($dbc, $query2) or die ('Error');

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($users)){
  print_r($row);
  echo "<br />";
  $user = $row['username'];
   while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tickets)){
   if(in_array($user, $row1)){
     print_r($row1);
     echo "<br />";
    }
 }

}

while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tickets)){
print_r($row1);
echo "<br />";
}
```

This is the output i get

```
Array ( [username] => aolusola )
Array ( [number] => 905495 [username] => aolusola [subject] => PAssword change Tool [name] =>  A Hotel )
Array ( [number] => 770279 [username] => aolusola [subject] => Laundry posting  [name] => Bfish Hotel )
Array ( [number] => 972356 [username] => aolusola [subject] => New TC  RVC 8 [name] => Inter Hotel )
Array ( [username] => cakaluka )
Array ( [username] => fmbah )
Array ( [username] => habel )
Array ( [username] => iadebanjo )
Array ( [username] => iakintade )
Array ( [username] => jajani )
Array ( [username] => jakinmosin )
Array ( [username] => jomaivboje )
Array ( [username] => logunleye )
Array ( [username] => oogundimu )
Array ( [username] => panawe )
Array ( [username] => solushola )
Array ( [username] => ugouvietesivwi )
```

The First user outputs according to plan, but the rest not so much. Any Idea what i am missing

Thanks

Comment: First comment the last loop and try again.

Comment: Can post the output of your queries separately?

Comment: You are consuming the COMPLETE `$tickets` result set in your first execution of the inner while loop. So therer is nothing left to process for the second, outer `$users` while loop

Comment: You would be better advised to write a single query to produce the output you require, as you obviouly have a field to JOIN on i.e. `username`

Comment: @LittlePhild Just looked at it again the last loop shouldnt be there, that a mistake

Comment: @RiggsFolly please pardon me, im still in the learning process...could you show me with an example

Comment: Wait for @mega6382 I think he is working on a better answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
$users = mysqli_query($dbc, $query2) or die ('Error');

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($users)){
  print_r($row);
  echo "<br />";
  $user = $row['username'];
$tickets = mysqli_query($dbc, $query1) or die ('Error');
   while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tickets)){
   if(in_array($user, $row1)){
     print_r($row1);
     echo "<br />";
    }
 }

}
```

Execute the query inside the while loop, because `mysqli_fetch_assoc` is forward only. So, you need to execute it every time the loop runs. OR you can only get tickets for current user only by this:

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'tickets2') or die('Error connecting to Mysql Server');

$query1 = " SELECT DISTINCT number, username, subject, o.name " .
"FROM ost_ticket t, ost_staff s, ost_ticket__cdata d, ost_user u, ost_organization o " .
"WHERE status_id = 1 AND t.staff_id=s.staff_id AND d.ticket_id=t.ticket_id AND u.id=t.user_id AND o.id=u.org_id " .
"ORDER by username";

$query2 = " SELECT DISTINCT username " .
"FROM ost_ticket t, ost_staff s, ost_ticket__cdata d, ost_user u, ost_organization o " .
"WHERE status_id = 1 AND t.staff_id=s.staff_id AND d.ticket_id=t.ticket_id AND u.id=t.user_id AND o.id=u.org_id " .
"ORDER by username";

$users = mysqli_query($dbc, $query2) or die ('Error');

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($users)){
  print_r($row);
  echo "<br />";
  $user = $row['username'];
$query3 = " SELECT DISTINCT number, username, subject, o.name " .
"FROM ost_ticket t, ost_staff s, ost_ticket__cdata d, ost_user u, ost_organization o " .
"WHERE `user_name` = '{$user}' status_id = 1 AND t.staff_id=s.staff_id AND d.ticket_id=t.ticket_id AND u.id=t.user_id AND o.id=u.org_id " .
"ORDER by username" ;
$tickets = mysqli_query($dbc, $query1) or die ('Error');
   while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tickets)){
     print_r($row1);
     echo "<br />";
 }

}

$tickets = mysqli_query($dbc, $query1) or die ('Error');
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tickets)){
print_r($row1);
echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: If you are going to suggest this then adding the `username` to the inner query so you only retrieve the relevant rows would also make a **lot** of sense. Then you could remove the silly `in_array` test and return NO unnecessary rows for each execution of the inner array

Answer (score 0):

It is very bad practice, to select data from db in loops. If you have many rows, your code will be very slow. You should make only one select, which will take data from both tables. Use JOIN (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)